# False Negatives Testing Value in FormControl

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an `Angular` component that edits data in an object loaded via `@Input()`:

```
export class EditFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() obj: IObject;
  editForm:FormGroup;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editForm = this.buildFormGroup();
    this.populateForm();
  }

  onClear = () => {

  };

  private buildFormGroup = ():FormGroup => {
    return new FormGroup({
      editFieldControl: new FormControl('', [])
    });
  };

  private populateForm = ():void => {
    this.editForm.controls.ediFieldControl.setValue(this.obj.field);
  }

}
```

The template for the component is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline"
          [formGroup]="editForm">
      <div class="col-xl-3">
        <label for="editFieldInput"
               class="sr-only">Field Value</label>
        <input id="editFieldInput"
               type="text"
               class="form-control-sm"
               placeholder="Field"
               formControlName="editFieldControl">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set up `TestBed` using `ng-cli` generated setup modified for my component:

```
let component: EditFormComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditFormComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ EditFormComponent ],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditFormComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.obj = {field: 'value'};
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

I can successfully test (and fail) the `onInit()` logic, so the form control's value is being set to the value of `obj.field` as expected. I then try to generate a failing test of the `onClear()` method:

```
it('should reset FormControls to their original value', () => {
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    component.editForm.controls.editFieldControl.setValue('test');
    component.onClear();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.editForm.controls.editFieldControl.value).toBe(component.obj.field);
    })
  });
});
```

Since `onClear()` is an empty method, i expect this test to fail, but it passes.  I played around a bit, trying unsuccessfully to generate a failure and eventually tried replacing the original expectation with:

```
expect(component.editForm.controls.editPackControl.value).toBe('111');
expect(component.editForm.controls.editPackControl.value).toBe('000');
```

Strangely enough, this impossible expectation also passed. I've tried restarting the `karma` server and then restarting `node` itself, but the false negatives persist. Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to correct it are welcome.

Comment: Did you try using async like `it('should reset FormControls to their original value', async(() => {`?

Comment: And i wonder what `this` refers to in the following code `.toBe(this.obj.field)`

Comment: @yurzui That "this" a typo, not in actual code. Probably happened when i was reducing the actual component code to something more readable. I tried injecting the `async` function previously without success.

Comment: Let's try to reproduce it. One minute

Comment: Please take a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/bdwACN68vJ4Or9QzJQyc?p=preview And here is failed test https://plnkr.co/edit/PpvXW3nVZEO5TjEGUq0E?p=preview

Comment: Weird. I swear i ran a test that looked just like the failing version you provided and it passed. I'll see if it works in my spec file and report back so you can answer & get your deserved rep. Much thanks.

Comment: @yurzui So, on further investigation, it seems that the problem was caused by nesting `describe` functions for some reasons. Injecting async still resulted in false negatives. Refactoring the spec into the top level `describe` with async resulting in a failing test.